# It's Starting To Happen!

Tags: discussion

I've noticed the visitors per day has been starting to creep up bit by bit and as I write, it is now at 309 visitors/day. Check out the [Quantcast stats](https://www.quantcast.com/genealogy.stackexchange.com) and under the graph select 3m or 6m for the date range, and you'll see the trend.

And we're averaging more than 1 new user a day. You can see that from the [New Users report order by creation date](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=NewUsers&sort=creationdate).

This is very good, and I don't think we're doing any extra work to make it happen, other than the good quality questions and answers that we've helped with. It's obviously the search engines that are bringing the people here, which is what is wanted by the Stack Exchange gang.

If this trend continues, it will be noticed, and we'll be on our way towards getting to our critical mass that can sustain itself and allow us to qualify for getting out of beta. It may still take a year or two, but now I'm optimistic again.

Keep those good Q&A's coming!

p.s. For anyone coming here who is new: This post is on the "meta" site. The actual Genealogy & Family History Q&A site you'll want to go to is at: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Our [visit per day statistics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43502/genealogy-family-history) today are Excellent (see below), and usually are nowadays:

[image]

Our only stat that Needs Work to help build a compelling case for our graduation is our questions per day.

I think our answers per question being only Okay will have negligible impact on our graduation case if our questions per day starts to climb.

Comment: This is great.We are improving. But do be aware that the statistics themselves are not what gets us out of beta. It's the determination by StackExchange staff that our community is self sustaining and has sufficient traffic from search tools like Google that it will continue to grow. Maybe the hits per day reaching the "Excellent" value is an indication that we are getting there. It might be time to contact a Stack Exchange Admin and ask whether we've established ourselves enough to come out of beta.

Comment: @lkessler Our case for graduation is nowhere near as strong as that of the [writers.se] Stack Exchange - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781 That Meta SE Q&A suggests changes to the graduation process appear closer.